# Get value of DateTime from a Datetime picker field

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, datetimepicker, python-datetime

I have 2 Datetime Picker fields like below:
[image]

I need to retrieve the value present on these 2 boxes, however, it is giving error each time I try a code:

stime= driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "datetimepicker-inner").**getitem**(3)
stime_val=stime.text

I have also tried with "textContent" and "Value", but still not returning the Datetime value.

Answer (score -1):

Try THIS:

```
stime = driver.find_element_by_class_name("datetimepicker-inner")
value = stime.get_attribute('value')
# value = stime.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Comment: Tried it ....not working :( ...any further suggestion please?

Comment: try to get value whit xpath

Answer (score -1):

This is resolved now. get_attribute worked after a lot of trial and errors.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).